# Visual studio installer doesn't start correctly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I just had to change my HDD. So I installed a version of Windows 10 Education on my computer, and now I'm trying to install Visual studio 2017 community/enterprise ( tried both ). After running the installer which was downloaded from the official website it doesn't start the installation, I just see for a tiny amount of time a small window pop but then it instantly shuts. What could be the reason for this behavior and how to fix this problem?

Edit: I can install other software, I managed to install a few other programs without a problem, I notice this behavior only with Visual studio and additionally .NET Framework installer.

Edit2:
I found this in my temp folder :

[4/20/2017, 11:30:37] === Logging started: 2017/04/20 11:30:37 ===
[4/20/2017, 11:30:37] [4/20/2017, 11:30:38] --- logging level: standard ---
[4/20/2017, 11:30:38] Directory 'C:\Users\2D94~1\AppData\Local\Temp\931f7233a5c56697278d79b1\' has been selected for file extraction
[4/20/2017, 11:30:38] Extracting files to: C:\Users\2D94~1\AppData\Local\Temp\931f7233a5c56697278d79b1\
[4/20/2017, 11:30:38] Error 0x8007002a: Failed to extract all files out of box container #0.
[4/20/2017, 11:30:38] Error 0x8007002a: Failed to extract
[4/20/2017, 11:30:38] Error 0x8007013d: Failed to get error string from error: 0x8007002a
[4/20/2017, 11:30:38] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x8007002a
[4/20/2017, 11:30:38] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0x0
[4/20/2017, 11:30:38] === Logging stopped: 2017/04/20 11:30:38 ===

Edit 3: THANKS MICROSOFT you really screwed me up huh.

Edit 4: After full Windows reinstall with the latest version still getting this error.

Edit 5: Changed windows version from education to professional and it works!

Comment: Could be any number of things. Try looking at your event log, and see if there's anything helpful there

Comment: @Jedediah after running it a few times, I do not see any errors/information appearing in the logs for the installer...

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. 

I thought visual studio was related to programming huh?

Answer (score 13):

Had the same issue. I was running installer from my /Download folder. 
Try move the installer to D: drive, it helped me.
Regards

Comment: Same problem and error as OP. Moved installer from Downloads folder to C:\. Installer magically starts working.

Comment: Thank you Maks, I'd have never figured it out... That's insane that there's no error that would make it even slightly easier for one to realize why the installer would just blink and not start... #windows